How to reset list in default argument after function call in Python?
I am learning Python and I have problem with default arguments. I know using mutable like list in default argument is not good because it keep the value between calls. Here is my example:
def append_to_list(value, my_list=[]):
    my_list.append(value)
    return my_list

# First call
result1 = append_to_list(1)
print(result1)  # Output: [1]

# Second call
result2 = append_to_list(2)
print(result2)  # Output: [1, 2]

I understand why this happens. Python is reusing the same list every time. People say I should use None and check inside the function, like this:
def append_to_list(value, my_list=None):
    if my_list is None:
        my_list = []
    my_list.append(value)
    return my_list

This works fine, but I don’t want to change the default argument to None. I want to still use my_list=[] but somehow make Python reset it after every call.
Is it possible to do this in Python? Maybe with some trick or something? Thank you for help!

You should change your default value to something immutable. Using None is the right way.

You could write a decorator that creates a new list and injects it. Still not great.

Don’t try to be clever or anything. Using None to mimic mutable defaults is considered best practice for good reason.
